# ACF and PACF with daily data

Tags: r, forecasting, acf-pacf

I am modeling with daily time series and some forecasting models from forecast package.But at the beginning I have some problem with time series.Namely I want to try to explain ACF and PACF but I can't find rational explanation in order to explain how seasonality (single or complex) can be spotted (daily,weekly,monthly etc.). In my opinion I think this series have daily and weekly seasonality but I am not sure.
So can anybody help me with this graphs ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what you are wanting is to be able to identify periodic oscillations of different frequencies in your data? Do you wish to impose 24 hour and 7 day periods or search for periodicity?

Comment: About first question I want to identify periodic oscillations of different frequencies in your data.About second question, data is on daily basis and I want to search for periodicity.My goal is to make msts object with complex frequency with msts function from forecast package and after I want to use this object intoTBATS model.